# How do I disable align to slide in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I cannot uncheck the "align to slide" option in PowerPoint 2007. It remains checked. I don't want any snapping to slide! I found some [strange discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other/cant-disable-align-to-slide/4874472a-675d-4f87-ac26-613685e435d7) about selecting more objects, but I don't want to select more objects, I want to disable the snapping while working with a single object.

Answer (score 1):

MS PowerPoint can be counter intuitive. This is one such situation.

Forget about unchecking 'Align to Slide', instead check 'Align to Selected Objects'.

'Align to Slide' and 'Align to Selected Objects' toggle with each other. 
I.e. When one is on, the other is off.

Don't want snapping or want more fine control?
Select an object --> Drawing tab --> Align --> Grid settings.
Uncheck snap to grid or change grid size.